# Ethereum Sepolia lightclient transaction validator

Tags: ethereum, web3js, consensus

I've searched for an Ethereum light-client to validate the transactions received from an API such as https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/.

In order to do this, I've found [Helios](https://github.com/a16z/helios) helpful. Hence, I started a light-client by this way `helios --network mainnet --consensus-rpc https://www.lightclientdata.org --execution-rpc https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/TOKEN`. Everything is OK, it works just like a proxy and it also proves transactions which got them from `execution-rpc`, but the problem is I want exactly this behavior for the Sepolia network. So, I'm going to change some of the parameters in previous command.

The final command looks like this `helios --network sepolia --consensus-rpc https://www.lightclientdata.org --execution-rpc https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/TOKEN` but I got this error...

```
2024-01-31T11:40:45.611365Z  INFO helios::rpc: rpc server started at 127.0.0.1:8545
2024-01-31T11:40:45.956658Z ERROR helios::consensus: sync failed err=could not fetch bootstrap
```

The problem is it can not prove transactions from https://www.lightclientdata.org. After two or three days in search of a consensus RPC for Sepolia network nothing was gained for me.

Is there a consensus endpoint? Should I use an alternative to Helios?

I want to know if there is any consensus RPC for Sepolia, or an alternative which looks like Helios?